# react-bootstrap-table - formatting - row height, text wrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am working with react-bootstrap-table  and I am facing problems with formatting it. Main issues are:

- the headers with long names should be presented with 2 lines of text, instead there is one and "..." like in the picture below:
  [image]
- Moreover in no way I could set the height of a single row of a table. Each text has big padding therefore the table is not too condensed:
  [image]

And the code goes here:

```
<BootstrapTable
   data={this.props.sales}
   version="4"
   striped
   hover
   pagination
   keyField="Type"
>
  {tableHeaders.map((header, index) => (
     <TableHeaderColumn key={index} dataField={header.id} style={{ height: 10 }}>
        {header.name}
     </TableHeaderColumn>
  ))}
</BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: its a css problem with text overflowing

Comment: inspect element. go the css class style.
you may find code like this ...
text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;

just remove them from css and that's all

Comment: and let me know if still facing issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [docs](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html) you can do all of the customizations you need.

**First issue:** To remove dots you can use `thStyle` property which you can pass to `TableHeaderColumn` component and override CSS `white-space` property.

```
<TableHeaderColumn thStyle={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }} {...anotherProps} />
```

**Second issue**: You can handle height of your row using `trClassName` property. You can either pass string or function to handle each or make conditional class depends on row. See more [here](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#trClassName).

For example:

```
<BootstrapTable trClassName="customClass" {...anotherProps} />
```

And define your `customClass`:

```
.customClass {
    // override padding or height whatever you want 
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks, both issue solved. To anyone struggling with second case - we have to use `line-height` property